# Hangman code having trouble accessing other file

Tags: python

So I made a program for hangman that accesses an input file but it is having trouble accessing it once I type it in.

This is the function that is calling the file

```
def getWord(filename):
    print("Loading from file...")
    inputFile = open(filename, 'r')
    wordlist = inputFile.read().splitlines()
    print(len(wordlist) + " lines loaded.")
    return wordlist


filename = input("What file will the words come from? ")
wordlist = getWord(filename)
theWordLine = random.choice(wordlist)
game(theWordLine)
```

And this is the file itself

```
person,Roger
place,Home
phrase,A Piece Of Cake
```

The error it is giving me is this

```
File "hangman.py' , line 77, in <module>
  wordlist = getWord(filename)
File "hangman.py' , line 10, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error states: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`. That means that you cannot use `+` with something of type `int` and something of type `str`. the `len` function returns an `int`. Thus you need to cast it into a `str` before you being able to concatenate it with another `str`

It should be `print(str(len(wordlist)) + " lines loaded.")` instead of `print(len(wordlist) + " lines loaded.")`

You may also want to use string formatting as a comment mentions. If you are using python 3.6 or higher, you can try f-strings: `f'{len(wordlist)} lines loaded}'`.

Comment: Or to use nicer string formatting `print('{} lines loaded.'.format(len(wordlist))`

Answer (score 0):

`print(len(wordlist) + " lines loaded.")` is causing your issue as it is trying to apply the `+` operand to variables of different datatypes.

You could use `print("{} lines loaded".format(len(wordlist)))` to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `print(len(wordlist), " lines loaded.")` instead of `print(len(wordlist) + " lines loaded.")`

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with reading the file. Read the error: an integer and string cannot be added.

Why are you getting this error? Because `len()` returns an integer, not a string. You can cast `len()`'s return to a string, or you can just use an f-string:

```
f'{len(wordlist)} lines loaded}'
```